# Error in Building a Xamarin Project for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, visual-studio-2019

I have downloaded a sample project from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/webservices-azurenotificationhub/

In  the building I got the error:
Failed to create JavaTypeInfo for class: Android.Support.V4.View.Accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat/IAccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor due to MAX_PATH: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:

I use Visual Studio 2019.

Thank you in advance,
Piero Sbressa

Comment: I download the sample from the link and test on my side. It works fine. The issue may be caused by the too long path. Try to move up the directory of the solution and simplify project name to reduce the overall path length. Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555021/11083277

Answer (score 0):

So this is definitely related to the MAX_PATH problem on Windows. This is a long dicussion about this [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/53#issuecomment-459062618) . Hopefully according to microsoft support team they are planing solve this issue and removing MAX_PATH as limit.

I would suggest to move your project to a "shorter" path.

I did not found an alternative. You can follow the discussion, hopefully they fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception, when I built the mobile application first. Error code was `XA4209` and suggested to: The fully qualified file name must be less than `260` characters, and the directory name must be less than `248` characters.

After I changed the number of characters in the path, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a number of things ,

1. best to move the directory closer to root say your drive name is C the closer to  "c:" the shorter the path the less likely this error will appear.
2. you could change the output path to be in a folder with shorter path , u find that in android project properties > build > output path
3. you can also change one of the parent folders name to be shorter , in my case i had a path 261 character long, i litteraly deleted one letter in a parent folder and fixed the issue.